# Android : tgid task_struct val

Tags: android, kernel

I have a daemon that I continuously start and do a 'kill -9' in a loop in order to stress test a particular use case. This daemon loads a shared library which in turn opens a fd. (opening / closing of fd is in another shared library code handled in kernel) . I observe that at the time of clean up operations in the kernel library, it checks for the PID value from task_structs, (tgid) before cleaning up . 
Now my observation : I sometime see that  when the daemon gets killed , i do not see a relevant tgid value instead i see a strange process ID value which of 'binder process'. As a result my clean up operations in the kernel code does not take in effect for that process ID that juts got killed by 'kill -9'

Any one knows why current->tgid value is that of a binder process and not of the daemon that gets killed. Note that my daemon does link to 'libbinder'. Not sure if that can make a difference. If I remove the linking to 'libbinder' and its relevant code from my daemon, everything seems fine

Any suggestions/ ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

If your userspace process opens a file, then forks another process, the open file will be duplicated in the forked process (it appears probable that this `libbinder` is forking off another process).

The close method of the `file_operations` struct in the kernel will only be called when the *last* reference to the file is put.  If both processes die around the same time, then the process which ends up calling the close method will be whichever one happens to die second.

Your kernel code should *not* be keying on `tgid`.  It should be attaching the data required for the cleanup operations to the `struct file`, **not** to the `task_struct`.

Comment: This info was certainly helpful. Thanks for the answer